# How to execute a stored procedure using DBTCloud

Tags: dbt

I am trying to use dbtcloud as an orchestration tool for loading a data warehouse.   The data is loaded via calling a series of stored procedures.  When trying to call a single stored proc via dbt, the sql executes successfully, but when I check the table no new data has loaded.  Here is a sample of how I am calling the proc.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
set autocommit=on;

call testschema.sample_proc(
'parm1', 
'parm2', 
'parm3' 
);
```

Comment: Please add more info to your question including the platform (SQL Server, MySql etc.), version, and language you are defining this procedure in.

Comment: syntax looks like snowflake